# How to plot a horizontal Stacked bar plot using Plotly-Python?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python, stacked-bar-chart

I'm trying to plot the below summary metric plot using plotly.

[image]

**data**

```
Model   F1_Score    Precision   Recall  Accuracy    ROC_AUC CV_Score
0   LogisticRegression  0.815068    0.777778    0.856115    0.739130    0.678058    0.752876
1   K-NearestNeighbors  0.828767    0.790850    0.870504    0.758454    0.699958    0.714476
2   SVM 0.852459    0.783133    0.935252    0.782609    0.702920    0.665067
3   GaussianProcess 0.825503    0.773585    0.884892    0.748792    0.677740    0.665067
4   MLP 0.774436    0.811024    0.741007    0.710145    0.694033    0.735327
5   DecisionTree    0.747170    0.785714    0.712230    0.676329    0.657586    0.692216
6   ExtraTrees  0.859060    0.805031    0.920863    0.797101    0.732490    0.792698
7   RandomForest    0.826667    0.770186    0.892086    0.748792    0.673984    0.778324
8   XGBoost 0.838488    0.802632    0.877698    0.772947    0.718261    0.764025
9   AdaBoostClassifier  0.800000    0.780822    0.820144    0.724638    0.674778    0.728927
10  GBClassifier    0.835017    0.784810    0.892086    0.763285    0.696043    0.754451
11  CatBoost    0.843854    0.783951    0.913669    0.772947    0.699482    0.768787
12  Stacking    0.833333    0.776398    0.899281    0.758454    0.684934    0.787949
13  Voting  0.836120    0.781250    0.899281    0.763285    0.692287    0.778337
14  Bagging 0.855263    0.787879    0.935252    0.787440    0.710273    0.792673
```

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

mark_color = ['rgba(246, 78, 139, 0.6)', 'rgba(58, 71, 80, 0.6)', 'rgba(50, 171, 96, 0.6)', 'rgba(38, 24, 74, 0.6)', 'rgba(155, 83, 109, 0.6)', 'rgba(297, 55, 74, 0.6)']
line_color = ['rgba(246, 78, 139, 1.0)', 'rgba(58, 71, 80, 1.0)', 'rgba(50, 171, 96, 1.0)', 'rgba(38, 24, 74, 1.0)', 'rgba(155, 83, 109, 1.0)', 'rgba(297, 55, 74, 1.0)']


y_labels = ["F1_Score", "Precision", "Recall", "Accuracy", "ROC_AUC", "CV_Score"]

fig = go.Figure()

for i, j in enumerate(y_labels):
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        y=y_labels,
        x=list(scores[j].values),
        name=j,
        orientation='h',
        marker=dict(
            color=mark_color[i]

        )
    ))

fig.update_layout(
    barmode='stack',
    title="Summary Metrics",
    xaxis_title="Metric Value",
    yaxis_title="Metric Name",
    legend_title="Model",

)

fig.show()
```

So far, I'm able to plot this

[image]

I'm unable to add Model Names to the plot. How add Model column as Legend and add all model values into the plot?

Comment: What are the problem(s) with your current plot? It looks like the colors and order of the model scores are as you have defined them

Comment: For legend(name), I don't know how to pass the model names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- shape the data frame first `df2 = df.set_index("Model").unstack().to_frame().reset_index()`
- then it's a simple case of using **Plotly Express**

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        """Model   F1_Score    Precision   Recall  Accuracy    ROC_AUC CV_Score
0   LogisticRegression  0.815068    0.777778    0.856115    0.739130    0.678058    0.752876
1   K-NearestNeighbors  0.828767    0.790850    0.870504    0.758454    0.699958    0.714476
2   SVM 0.852459    0.783133    0.935252    0.782609    0.702920    0.665067
3   GaussianProcess 0.825503    0.773585    0.884892    0.748792    0.677740    0.665067
4   MLP 0.774436    0.811024    0.741007    0.710145    0.694033    0.735327
5   DecisionTree    0.747170    0.785714    0.712230    0.676329    0.657586    0.692216
6   ExtraTrees  0.859060    0.805031    0.920863    0.797101    0.732490    0.792698
7   RandomForest    0.826667    0.770186    0.892086    0.748792    0.673984    0.778324
8   XGBoost 0.838488    0.802632    0.877698    0.772947    0.718261    0.764025
9   AdaBoostClassifier  0.800000    0.780822    0.820144    0.724638    0.674778    0.728927
10  GBClassifier    0.835017    0.784810    0.892086    0.763285    0.696043    0.754451
11  CatBoost    0.843854    0.783951    0.913669    0.772947    0.699482    0.768787
12  Stacking    0.833333    0.776398    0.899281    0.758454    0.684934    0.787949
13  Voting  0.836120    0.781250    0.899281    0.763285    0.692287    0.778337
14  Bagging 0.855263    0.787879    0.935252    0.787440    0.710273    0.792673"""
    ),
    sep="\s+",
)

df2 = df.set_index("Model").unstack().to_frame().reset_index()

fig = px.bar(
    df2,
    y="level_0",
    x=0,
    color="Model",
    color_discrete_map={
        "LogisticRegression": "#2E91E5",
        "K-NearestNeighbors": "#E15F99",
        "SVM": "#1CA71C",
        "GaussianProcess": "#FB0D0D",
        "MLP": "#DA16FF",
        "DecisionTree": "#222A2A",
        "ExtraTrees": "#B68100",
        "RandomForest": "#750D86",
        "XGBoost": "#EB663B",
        "AdaBoostClassifier": "#511CFB",
        "GBClassifier": "#00A08B",
        "CatBoost": "#FB00D1",
        "Stacking": "#FC0080",
        "Voting": "#B2828D",
        "Bagging": "#6C7C32",
    },
)

fig.update_layout(
    title="Summary Metrics",
    xaxis_title="Metric Value",
    yaxis_title="Metric Name",
    legend_title="Model",
)
```

[image]

Comment: How to add custom colors for the bars?

Comment: updated - use **color_discrete_map**